# Ruby Net::HTTP Get request Error when using https

Tags: ruby, https, get, net-http

I have a web server that i need to get some data from. I want to reuse the connection, that's why i chose `HTTP.new`

```
require "net/http"
require "openssl"
uri = URI.parse("https://example.com")
path = "/index.html"
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port,
    :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https')
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new "/index.html"
response = http.request(request)
```

When issuing the request (`response = http.request(request)`) ruby throws a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from (irb):14
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

The same request works when i use http

Comment: To me it seems the issue is actually here `Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https')` because this does not match the signature for `Net::HTTP.new` which does not accept a `Hash`. The method signature is `new(address, port = nil, p_addr = :ENV, p_port = nil, p_user = nil, p_pass = nil)`. I think it should be `http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port); http.use_ssl = uri.scheme == 'https';`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you aren't overcomplicating the invocation.  Why not just use:

```
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
```

I'm basing this on the assumption that you already know whether or not your target server requires HTTPS or not.